# How to execute fuction untill next function is execute

Tags: javascript

```
setOcrProccesing() {
    .....
    this.setProgressBarSimulation();
}

setOcrMessage() {
   ......
}

setProgressBarSimulation() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.ocrProgress += 10;
        if(this.ocrProgress == 100) {
            this.ocrProgress = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Method setOcrProccesing() is execute first and in this situation methodSetProgressBarSimulation() is execute only one how to that this method is working untill setOcrMessage() is execute ?

Comment: In order to be able to execute any other function, `setOcrProccesing` [sic] must yield flow control back to the event loop somewhere; i.e. it must `return` or `await` some asynchronous operation. Does it ever do that? If not, nothing else will have any chance of executing anything.

Comment: setOcrMessage() wait for response from API

Comment: Are you just looking for `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?  Or what do you mean by "this method is working until..."?  What should this method be *doing* during that time?

Comment: This method 
simulating progress on progress bar. Now it's execute only one and 
progress on the bar is 10%.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Promise - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @David Thanks i use setInterval and work fine